# Dot Net Core 2 Code to serve a .plist file to an ios device for installation of an iOS application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, plist, ipa

I am creating a **dot net core mvc app** to allow my internal team to download the **enterprise ios app** on their phones. So I created a **plist to put (serve)** it in that app and allow users to download and install the mobile app through this dot net app.

Below is the **Downloadapp** action that takes a string with a file name and returns the plist file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Downloadapp(string filename)
        {
            string file_name = getFileName(filename);
            string file_path = getFilePath(filename);

            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename not present");

            var path = Path.Combine(
                           Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                           file_path, file_name);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

I call this: https://localhost:44384/Home/Downloadapp?filename=CCI_Zoom_iOS_Mobile_plist to download the plist successfully and have https://localhost:44384/Home/Downloadapp?filename=CCI_Zoom_iOS_Mobile_ipa in the plist string to call and serve the ipa file.

However, When I call

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://localhost:44384/Home/Downloadapp?filename=CCI Zoom_iOS_Mobile_plist

using a **URL.Action** call/also append itms-services.... in the beginning of the URL, it says **"Open this page in itunes"** and then nothing happens.

On an ios device, normally it should give an **option to install the application** but in my case nothing is happening.

**What dot net core (2.1) code shall I write to generate a link that serves a plist file to download an ios application?**

p.s. I am new to .net core so I need your help on this. It would be much appreciated.

Thanks